# PIC18F timer for minutes and hours

Tags: c, microcontroller, pic

```
#include<p18f452.h>
void T0_init(); 
void main()
{
    TRISC=0;        // Configure PortB as output Port.
    LATC=0x01;
    T0CON=0x07;     // Prescaler= 1:256, 16-bit mode, Internal Clock
    T0_init();
    while(1)
    {
            // Initialize Timer0
            LATC=0x00;
            T0_init();      //Delay for 1 sec
            LATC=0x01;
            T0_init();     //Again delay for 1 sec
    }
}

void T0_init()
{
    int a=0;

    //while(a<2)   // {
    TMR0H=0xF0;    // Values calculated for 1 second delay with 4MHz crystal
    TMR0L=0xBD;    //4/4MHz =1us=1us*prescaler=256us=1sec/256u=0xF42-(FFFF)=F0BD
    T0CONbits.TMR0ON=1;         // Timer0 On
    while(INTCONbits.TMR0IF==0);        // Wait until TMR0IF gets flagged
    T0CONbits.TMR0ON=0;                 // Timer0 Off
    INTCONbits.TMR0IF=0;                // Clear Timer0 interrupt flag
    //   a++;
    //  }
}
```

It is very accurate delay and it is doing its work but I want longer delays like of hours or minutes. So , what to do for longer delays. I tried using counter which increments on every  flagged, but it does not work.

Comment: Any Body Home I am waiting For reply any answers??

Comment: I'm not sure, but it is possible that you have to enable the interrupt first by setting TMR0IE=1.

Comment: Is `int a` the counter you tried? If so you need to declare it 'static'.

Comment: Making a counter variable or wrapping your delay function in a `for` loop (or two, or three) really isn't that hard. Give it a try.

Comment: @AndrewMedico thanks for ur concern but I have to use timer in this.

Comment: @jolati Is static means that a's value will not be destroyed or is it something else?

Comment: Yes, a [static variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_variable) exists for the life of the program. Your variable `int a` is only allocated (only exists) when the function `void T0_init()' is called.

Comment: Yes, and only need a in that function :)

Answer (score 0):

A second is 1000000 microseconds, that is less than 256*256*256=16777216. So a 256-prescaled 16-bit timer is sufficient to count a second. But it's not enough to count a minute.

The solution is to add a `for` loop to count the seconds. And another one for minutes, and another one for hours, as suggested by @Andrew .

A source of uncertainty is that the overflow of the timer is checked once in the `while()` loop. So if long computations are performed in that loop, the precision will decrease. To overcome this, using interrupts is the way to go. Whatever is happening, as the overflow of the timer occurs, the interrupt flag is raised and the interruption function is executed within a few cycles.

Since nothing is done in the `while(1)` loop, i wanted to use the `SLEEP()` command to spare some energy. Unfortunately, the timer0 is switched off by the `SLEEP()` command. It is not the case of timer1, but timer1 is a 8-prescaled 16-bit timer... So a for loop is needed to count a second.

Here is a code compiled by XC8 and tested with the simulator of MPLAB X...

```
#include <xc.h>

#pragma config WDT=OFF


volatile unsigned char nb;
volatile unsigned char seconds;
volatile unsigned char minutes;
volatile unsigned char hours;

void interrupt high_isr (void)
{

    if(PIR1bits.TMR1IF) //interrupt flag of TIMER1
    {
        if(nb==0){
            TMR1H=0;    // Values calculated for 1 second delay with 4MHz crystal
            TMR1L=0;
            nb=1;//4/4MHz =1us=1us*prescaler=8us=1sec/8u=...
        }else{
            TMR1H=23;
            TMR1L=184;
            nb=0;
        }

        if(nb==1){
            seconds++;
            if(seconds==60){
                seconds=0;
                minutes++;
                if(minutes==60){
                    minutes=0;
                    hours++;

                }
            }
        }
        PIR1bits.TMR1IF=0;  //erase interrupt flag of TIMER1
    }
}

void interrupt low_priority low_isr (void)
{

}

void main(void) {
    //OSCCON=0x7D;//Internal oscillator, 8Mhz


    T1CONbits.RD16=1;  //timer1 is a 16-bit timer
    T1CONbits.T1CKPS1=1; //prescaler 11 -> 8-prescaled
    T1CONbits.T1CKPS0=1;
    T1CONbits.TMR1ON=1;// switch on timer1

    TMR1H=0x00; //setting timer1 : high bit first
    TMR1L=0x00;

    //   TMR0H=0;
    //   TMR0L=0;

    TRISC=0;
    LATC=0x00;

    INTCON2bits.TMR0IP=0; // low priority interuption timer0
    IPR1bits.TMR1IP=1;   // high priority interuption  timer1

    INTCONbits.TMR0IF=0;//erase interruption flap if set
    PIR1bits.TMR1IF=0; //erase interruption flag if set

    RCONbits.IPEN=1;// Interruption prioritaires

    INTCONbits.TMR0IE=0;// interuption activation on timer0 (0=no active)

    PIE1bits.TMR1IE=1;//enable interupt on timer1

    nb=1;
    seconds=0;
    minutes=0;
    hours=0;
    PORTCbits.RC0=0;
    PORTCbits.RC1=0;
    PORTCbits.RC2=0;
    INTCONbits.GIEH=1;// autorise interuptions
    INTCONbits.GIEL=1;
    // INTCONbits.GIE=1;



    while(1){
        //problem with modulo and pic...do not use %
        if(seconds-2*(seconds/2)==1){
            PORTCbits.RC0=1;
        }else{
            PORTCbits.RC0=0;
        }

        if(minutes-2*(minutes/2)==1){
            PORTCbits.RC1=1;
        }else{
            PORTCbits.RC1=0;
        }

        if(hours-2*(hours/2)==1){
            PORTCbits.RC2=1;
        }else{
            PORTCbits.RC2=0;

        }
        SLEEP();
    }
    return;
}
```

The duration of a "second" is subjected to caution...Playing with `TMR1H`,`TMR1L` and `nb` may be required.

And using an external clock source (quartz) is better : [How to make Timer1 more accurate as a real time clock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24560793/how-to-make-timer1-more-accurate-as-a-real-time-clock/24561624#24561624)

Comment: Thanks for answer..
I will try it tomorrow I am way from My pc for a day so wait till then I ll add comment again regarding my query BTW thanks.

Comment: I tried your code but My compiler is giving error on #include<xc.h>
I check my h files on MPLABX it does not contain any file of that name :(

Comment: `<xc.h>` is the header corresponding to the xc8 compiler. Go to `project->properties->Conf[default]` (right click on project name) and choose XC8 as compiler toolchain. A free (or non-free) version of xc8 may be downloaded [at microchip](http://www.microchip.com/pagehandler/en_us/devtools/mplabxc/). Or try to change the header by `#include<p18f452.h>`. And you may have to add something like `#pragma code high_vector=0x08` before `void high_isr(void)`, `#pragma code low_vector=0x18` before `void low_isr(void)` and `#pragma code` before main.

Comment: I was running project on C18
I am downloading XC8 :)

Comment: I added a few comments about timer1.

Comment: I don't get it...
On overflow which function is called??
what is purpose of using nb??

Comment: On overflow, the interrupt flag `PIR1bits.TMR1IF` is raised and the high priority interrupt routine `high_isr()` is called. `nb` counts the number of overflows...I needed it because timer1 can't count a second directly since the prescaler of timer1 can't be higher than 8. So timer1 loops starting from 0 when `nb==0` and starting from 23*256+184 when `nb==1`. The counter `seconds` is incremented when `nb==1`. Notice : `256*256*2-23*256-184=125000`

Comment: What should be the output of it
'RC0' will glow after every second
'RC1' after every minute
'RC2' after every one hour
but it aint working :/       and another thing in sleep() all the previous values remains or not For Example: PORTC=0xFF; then sleep(); will PORTC on or off?

Comment: I tested the code using the simulator of mplabx...and i failed to see a problem. `seconds`, `minutes` and `hours` work fine, the problem is `hours%2==1` is not the modulo function...See http://www.microchip.com/forums/m255849.aspx for instance. Using `hours-2*(hours/2)==1` may do the trick... I will edit the answer...

Comment: have u checked it on Proteus??

Comment: Can I text your privately...
its really time wasting to do commenting

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an experienced programmer and not sure exactly where you want to use your delays in, but I had tried to make a lengthy delay with pic18f4550 but it didnt work, i.e. for minutes and hours. But I have considered using an IC like, CD4060 or DS1307. you can follow this link for CD4060:  http://dmohankumar.wordpress.com/2012/05/13/design-your-circuit-part-ii-cd-4060-timer/. For DS1307 you can check up in studentcompanion site: http://www.studentcompanion.co.za/post/Digital-Clock-using-PIC-Microcontroller-and-the-DS1307-Real-Time-Clock-XC8-Compiler/. I wish you success, thanks

Comment: thanks for your concern Tiras 
but i have to make code for PIC :)

Answer (score 0):

forget the internal timer and do a busy wait routine on your own: make first a 1-second delay routine (very simple to do it accurately, take care of the call and retf execution time!), then make a 1-minute delay routine on top of the first, then make a 1-hour delay routine on top of the 1-minute... you get the idea.

Comment: sorry!!
But I have to use Timer in it because delay will be input by user at run time and it will change every time you know what i am trying to say
run time value

Comment: Mmm it's not clear. Are u saying that it must run concurrently with the user input?

Comment: yes, later on i have to take input from keypad and calculate its signal

Comment: ok, so you could use the timer *only* for the 1-second routine letting your code to scan the keyboard. The 1-minute and 1-hour routines are just for loops for your 1-second function. The external for loops (the one for the 1-minute and 1-hour routines) are so fast that most of the time is spent inside the 1-second routine letting your code scan the keyboard during the whole delay.

Comment: problem with ur logic is that there is Watch Dog timer in PIC which will reset after 2.3 Sec to avoid damage to PIC by any case.
Timer1 turns off WDT

Comment: I dont know If the watch dog is required.

Comment: Watch dog auto Reset Program counter so u cant get delay more than 2.3 sec